# Сопоставление данных одной таблицы MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

В базе данных у меня категории задаются id авто инкремент, тобишь допустим id1 - экономика, id2 - политика. Ну и при выводе я получаю "Категория: 1", хотелось бы, чтоб вместо id подставлялось полное название категории, допустим "Категория: Экономика"... Как такое можно реализовать, если не сложно, покажите на примере кода?

Comment: Вы не потрудились привести схему ваших таблиц, почему кто-то должен догадываться как у вас сделано и давать соответсвующий ответ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT `category` FROM `tablica` WHERE id='1'.
```

Как-то так. На `PHP`:

```
$sql="SELECT `category` FROM `tablica` WHERE id=$id;";
$row=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql, $conn));
$cat=$row[0];
echo "Категория: $cat";
```

Comment: Два запроса вместо одного? Зачем лишняя нагрузка.

Comment: Первую строку не смотреть. Она для наглядности стоит.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте LEFT JOIN.